# Add a State property to an Inline Style in React

Tags: css, reactjs, styles, state

I have a react element that has an inline style like this: (Shortened version)

```
      <div className='progress-bar'
           role='progressbar'
           style={{width: '30%'}}>
      </div>
```

I want to replace the width with a property from my state, although I'm not quite sure how to do it.

I tried:

```
      <div className='progress-bar'
           role='progressbar'
           style={{{width: this.state.percentage}}}>
      </div>
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
style={ { width: `${ this.state.percentage }%` } }
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/9manu4vs/)

Answer (score 3):

yes its possible check below

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      width:30; //default
    };
  }


  render(){

//when state changes the width changes
const style = {
  width: this.state.width
}

  return(
    <div>
    //when button is clicked the style value of width increases
      <button onClick={() => this.setState({width + 1})}></button>
      <div className='progress-bar'
           role='progressbar'
           style={style}>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

:-)

Comment: do you use a tool to add the semicolons automatically?

Comment: you can set up eslint on save in vscode to do that