# How to change style of a different component on button click in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to apply a width of 100% to my navbar on click of a button. Intially, it would be 0% (hidden). 
To do this, I use a state to keep track of the navbar width, However, it seems that my state wouldn't change onclick.

```
class Navbar extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      sidenav: {
        width: '0%',
      }
    }
  }

  showNavBar = () => {
    this.setState({
      sidenav: {
        width: '100%',
      }
    })
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <div className ="sidenav" style ={{width : this.state.sidenav.width}}>
          <NavLink exact to="/">Home</NavLink>
          <NavLink exact to="/about">About</NavLink>
          <NavLink exact to="/portfolio">Portfolio</NavLink>
          <NavLink exact to="/contacts">Contacts</NavLink>
          <div className="content">
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
            <Route exact path="/portfolio" component={Portfolio} />
            <Route exact path="/contacts" component={Contacts} />
            </div>
        </div>
        <NavbarButton onClick={this.showNavBar}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
};
```

Can anyone point out where I went wrong?

**EDIT:**

So I followed the examples you guys posted and got it working only when I explicitly give the  in the render function.

So here is my code for the NavBarbutton, maybe someone can see why it's wrong?

```
const NavbarButton = (props) => {
  return (
    <button style = {style} onClick = {props.showNavBar}>☰</button>
  )
}
```

Comment: Have you seen this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37827279/4636715

Comment: Your state is not changing or the styling is not updating? Do a `console.log(this.state)` inside the `render()` function to see if the stats is updating after the click.

Comment: Something is wrong with your `css`. The code works fine. Check this codesandbox example i quickly created https://codesandbox.io/s/o7p3xw8jz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is because I don't know how to properly pass props to the child component.

```
 const NavbarButton = (props) => {
  return (
    <button style = {style} onClick = {props.showNavBar}>☰</button>
  )
}
```

My code should have been

```
<NavbarButton showNavBar={this.showNavBar}/>
```

Gosh I feel so stupid now!

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, that is the width is getting from 0% to 100%.

Here is a codesandbox derived from the code you provided.

https://codesandbox.io/s/lx24555w8z

If you want to show the navbar on click, then probably use the display property instead of the width.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS display property instead.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Navbar extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      showNavBar: false
    };
  }

  showNavBar = () => {
    this.setState({
      showNavBar: true
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div
          className="sidenav"
          style={{ display: this.state.showNavBar ? "block" : "none" }}
        >
          <NavLink exact to="/">
            Home
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink exact to="/about">
            About
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink exact to="/portfolio">
            Portfolio
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink exact to="/contacts">
            Contacts
          </NavLink>
          <div className="content">
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
            <Route exact path="/portfolio" component={Portfolio} />
            <Route exact path="/contacts" component={Contacts} />
          </div>
        </div>
        <NavbarButton onClick={this.showNavBar} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Navbar;
```