# react how to pass props to inline css style in components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I need to draw some colored squares and use props to control the color of these squares.

The current code is not working

```
   import React from "react"; 

   class SketchExample extends React.Component {

   constructor(props) {
    super(props);   
   }


   render() {
    const { color } = this.props;

    return <div style={{ color: this.props.color, width: "36px", height: "36px" }} />;   } }

   export default SketchExample;
```

And the app.js file

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import SketchExample from "./SketchExample";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SketchExample color={{ r: "201", g: "112", b: "19", a: "1" }} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Which part went wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/37827390/2427237

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing `color` will make the text inside the `div` of that color.

What you need it `backgroundColor` to make "colored squares".

Also, you can't pass an object to a styles, it need to be a string.

```
return (
    <div 
        style={{ backgroundColor: `rgba(${Object.values(this.props.color).join(", ")})`, width: "36px", height: "36px" }} 
    /> 
);
```

Answer (score 2):

From a quick glance of your code I can see you pass a `color` prop to `SketchExample` which is an object with props such as `r` and `g` and etc. Yet inside `SketchExample` the `div`s `style.color` is the object, not the actual color. Try something like this:

```
render() {
    const { color } = this.props;

    return <div style={{ 
        color: `rgba(${color.r},${color.g},${color.b},${color.a})`,
        width: "36px",
        height: "36px" 
    }} />
}
```